# How to access SAPUI5 component from utility functions?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to access my SAPUI5 app component using this.getOwnerComponent() from a utility function, for example formatter or a class function, this works from controllers but in a utility or formatter function placed in another folder doesn't work. I do not want to use sap.ui.getCore(), is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Where do you call your utility function?

Comment: It will be called from within the controllers..

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the controller instance to your utility class in the constructor, and then access its owner component. You could also try injecting the component directly. Unfortunately, I am not sure if any of these is the preferred way in UI5 development.

That would couple the utility function to the component logic though, which I do not think is a good idea, you probably should pass only what is required for the utility function to do its' job.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility but it was not a clean implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with below two choices:
1. Create the utility functiona as a singleton class and pass the component one time with a setComponent method. 
2. Use event bus to fire events and get things done by component that can be done only within the component like accessing oData resources